# Simple java console calculator

Tags: java

Without directly giving me the answer can someone help me with this simple calculator that I am trying to write?
Everything seem to work well except for the very end when I ask the user to make a choice for add,subtract, multiply, or divide.  It does not allow me to enter my choices in the console.
I think it has something to do with the array of String that I created and the if statement.  Not sure.  Any tips would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class simpleCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //declare my variables
        int firstNum;
        int secondNum;
        int division = 0, addition = 0, subtraction = 0, multiplication = 0;
        String userChoice = "";
        String choices[] = {"add","multiply","divide","subtract"};

        //ask for user input
        System.out.print("Please enter first number: ");
        firstNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter second number: ");
        secondNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What type of operation would you like to perform on these numbers?");
        System.out.println("add " +"multiply " +"subtract " + "divide ");
        userChoice = input.nextLine();

        if (userChoice == "add"){
                    System.out.print("Answer = " + addition);
        }


        //calculator formulas
        addition = firstNum + secondNum;
        multiplication = firstNum * secondNum;
        subtraction = firstNum - secondNum;
        division = firstNum / secondNum;

    }

}
```

Comment: just add another `input.nextLine()` before `userChoice = input.nextLine();` and to compare String, use `userChoice .equals("add")`

Comment: to continue your program running for different inputs use a while loop  - `while(input.hasNext(){ //your code}`

Comment: Try using instead of `input.nextLine()` use `input.next()`

Comment: Also make sure you perform the addition in a separate function, because you are only printing the value 0 right now, no matter what number you input.

Comment: Oh that's so cool.  I was wondering why I was getting back 0.  Had no idea what you meant by performing the addition in a separate function.  Moved it and voila! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nextInt() reads just the number and not the end of the line after the number.  You will need a nextLine() after each nextInt() to consume the rest of the line.

Also, before you beat your head against the wall the following statement won't work for you:

```
if (userChoice == "add")
```

== tests for reference equality.

.equals() tests for value equality.  So you need something like this instead:

```
if (userChoice.equals("add"))
```

I wanted to give you that freebie because I love your attitude that you don't want anyone to give you the answer.  That is great that you wan to learn it.  Keep up the good work.

Comment: well what I was hoping to accomplish there was test what the user inputs with that array of String that I created and apparently did not utilize yet.  Thanks again guys for the tips. I'll go mess around with this thing some more.

Comment: Either way, my point holds.  You shouldn't use == to compare String values.  You should always use the .equals() function when comparing string values.  Your statement as it stands now will be false even if the value of userChoice is equals to "add".

Answer (score 0):

Saying that String a == String b means that you're comparing two strings to see if they have reference equality, while saying a.equals(b) will compare the values stored in the string.

Reference equality is used to compare whether two object references point to the same object, which in this case you shouldn't be using as you're trying to compare whether the value of two variables are equal. So definitely go with

```
if(userChoice.equals("add"))
```

Comment: So just to be clear, if I had an array of String and I wanted to compare those value with what the user inputted then I would use == ?

Comment: If you want to compare the values of a and b, use the method a.equals(b)

Comment: In this scenario, you won't have a need to use == to compare the two strings. I hope that helps :)